# Returning multiple columns in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want returning a array of objects and a count, but the following code is returning a error. Why?

Class ProdutoController

```
public static function listarTableDezMaisVendidos(){
    $retorno = "<table border='1' class='table-striped '>"
            . "<tr><th>Cod.</th>"
            . "<th>Nome</th>"
            . "<th>Quantidade de Vendas</th>"
            . "<th>Preço de Custo</th>"
            . "<th>Preço de Venda</th>"
            . "<th>Quantidade em estoque</th>"
            . "<th></th>"
            . "<th></th></tr>";

            $retorno = daogenerico::listarDezMaisVendidos();
            $itens = $retorno[0];
            $quantidades = $retorno[1];

    for($i=0; $i<count($itens); $i++){
        $item = $itens[$i];
        $retorno .= "<tr><td><form method='POST' action='cadproduto.php'>".$item->getProduto()->getId()."</td>"
                . "<td>".$item->getProduto()->getNome()."</td>"
                . "<td>".""."</td>"
                . "<td>".$item->getProduto()->getPrecodecusto()."</td>"
                . "<td>".$item->getProduto()->getPrecodevenda()."</td>"
                . "<td>".$item->getProduto()->getQuantidade()."</td>"
                . "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$item->getProduto()->getId()."'>"
                . "<input type='hidden' name='nome' value='".$item->getProduto()->getNome()."'>"
                . "<input type='hidden' name='descricao' value='".$item->getProduto()->getDescricao()."'>"
                . "<input type='hidden' name='precodecusto' value='".$item->getProduto()->getPrecodecusto()."'>"
                . "<input type='hidden' name='precodevenda' value='".$item->getProduto()->getPrecodevenda()."'>"
                . "<input type='hidden' name='quantidade' value='".$item->getProduto()->getQuantidade()."'>"
                . "<input type='hidden' name='quantidademinima' value='".$item->getProduto()->getQuantidademinima()."'>"
                . "<input type='hidden' name='opcao' value='editar'>"
                . "<td><button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'>Editar</button></td></form>"
                . "<td><a class='btn btn-default' href='".CONTROLE."postproduto.php?id=".$item->getProduto()->getId()."&AMP;opcao=excluir'>Excluir</a></td></tr>";
    }
    $retorno .= "</table>";
    return $retorno;
}
```

Class daogenerico

```
public static function listarDezMaisVendidos(){
    $bd = new bd();
    $bd->conectar();
    $result = $bd->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT i, count(p.id) AS ct FROM Item i JOIN i.produto p GROUP BY p ORDER BY ct DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(10)
    ->getResult();

    return $result; 
}
```

Error in broswer:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TrabalhoA2\controller\ProdutoController.php on line
>   244
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TrabalhoA2\controller\ProdutoController.php on line
>   228
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getProduto() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TrabalhoA2\controller\ProdutoController.php on line
>   229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors here:

1. You declare `$retorno` as a string (`$retorno = "<table>"...1`), then you redeclare it with an array (`$retorno = daogenerico::listarDezMaisVendidos();`) and finally you are trying to append string to array (`$retorno .=`) which is why you get `Array to string conversion` error.
2. `$retorno` is an array. Each element of array is a row of database. So doing `$itens = $retorno[0]` and then `$quantidades = $retorno[1];` is not doing what you meant. `$itens` is now first row of db and `$quantidades` is second row of db. It looks like your query returns only one row that's why you get `Undefined offset: 1`
3. You should really read about separating view from business logic. For example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for aswer, but i get the solution in http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html. Sorry for inconvenience.